# Export Facebook events to an excel sheet

Tags: facebook, events, export

I have been looking on google to find a easy way to convert/export an Facebook event with an URL link to the event to an excel sheet with all the information the event has. Like name of event, start date, end date, location etc but without luck on how it can be done.

Any suggestions on how this can be done?

Comment: Please specify your question. What have you found? What have you already tried out?

Comment: I am making an app for students, where they can see all the events that are at the campus. To make it easier for the students to share their events, I want them just to share the Facebook URL at the website I am making.
The website then export all the information in the Facebook events to a excel sheets or google sheets, that I then upload to the app itself.

I have tried exporting it to google calendar and then to a google sheets without any success.
Sorry for my bad English, I hope I made it easy to understand. If not I will explain better.

Comment: How have you tried to export this data? Via some functionality Facebook officially offers via the UI, or …? If you want to implement this yourself, then the way to go would be via API, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event/ But depending on the event type/settings/owner, you might not have access to all events, some might require that the event owner grants your app permission first.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will look into the Facebook api and see what I can do about that.